# html / image inside textview in iphone

Tags: iphone

Data is coming in json field like,

**"desc":"http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg Hello World"**

Image will be at the random place.

So can it be possible to show html / image inside textview ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do same in `UITextView`

You can use `UIWebView` in place of it, it provides all functionality as you asked in your question.

Hope it helps you....

Answer (score 0):

Use [bctextview](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bctextview) link for html display.